# How to match two sets of data by dates which do not synchronise and include missing values in Excel

Tags: excel, join, merge, excel-formula, dataset

Please forgive any errors or shortcomings in this question, it's my first on stackoverflow.

I have two sets of data in Excel of differing lengths and frequency, and would like to be able to place a value of 0 for where they don't synchronise, and match the rest.

For example, dataset 1 could be:

```
Date        Set1
01-01-2010  10
01-03-2010  4
01-04-2010  8
01-05-2010  5
01-06-2010  10
01-09-2010  12
01-10-2010  9
01-11-2010  4
```

And dataset 2 could be:

```
Date        Set2
01-03-2010  102
01-06-2010  104
01-10-2010  102
```

I'm looking for an output table that displays the values alongside each other for dates matching, 0 otherwise, like so:

```
Date        Set1   Set2
01-01-2010  10      0
01-03-2010  4       102
01-04-2010  8       0
01-05-2010  5       0
01-06-2010  10      104
01-09-2010  12      0
01-10-2010  9       102
01-11-2010  4       0
```

I can't seem to be able to crack this with my limited knowledge and the lack of synchronisation in the data. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a `VLOOKUP` nested in an `IFERROR` statement.

The two equations used (and dragged down to last unique date row) are:

`H3 = IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G3,A:B,2,0),0))` & `I3 = IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G3,D:E,2,0),0))`

[image]

---

This will **not** work if you have duplicate dates in the same data set with varying values since `VLOOKUP` will always return the first matched value (reading top down).

Comment: I probably would have included a 0, 0 entry for 1/2/2010, 1/7/2010 and 1/8/2010 but this seems the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Place Set1 in A1:B9 (header in row 1). Add a column of zeros next to it in column C, so A2:A9 is dates, B2:B9 is values and C2:C9 is zeros.

Place Set2 (without the header) in A10:B12; move the Set2 data to column C and put zeros in column B, so A10:A12 is dates, B10:B12 is zeros, C10:C12 is values.

Sort the range A2:C12 by Date (column A).

Easier to show with a screenshot but newbies are not allowed to post images.